# CSS: Change from 4 images in 1 row to 2 images in 2 rows

Tags: css, response

I have 4 images in 1 row.
I need to make them change in 2 images in 2 rows when is responce view active.
How can I do that?

[Here is my page, I need to fix 4 iframes at the bottom](http://adrk.de/index.php/de/rasse)

Comment: I suggest you rewrite your question, the reason being that there are several problems with it:

1. Your code sample is incomplete, it contains no css nor actual images
2. Your code sample includes an iframe,  which possibly indicates you are taking content from another site, which in turn means you cannot restyle it as far as I know

Provide these missing bits and we can help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, now that you added a link to your page, the answer is simple. Your  have a fixed pixel width value for each iframe. If you want to limit it to 2 per row, simply give the iframe element a `float:left;` , `width:50%;` and `margin:0 0 10px 0;` (to get rid of the lateral margins you have which make the total width go beyond 100%) per class, for starters. After that, all you need after that is to play with margin/padding values to get the desired spacing/specific look you're after.

In summary, try adding this to your css:

```
iframe {
   float:left;
   width:50%;
   margin:0 0 10px 0 !important;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Sotkra.
Is there a way that I can center those iframes in responsive view?
Right now, when I do as you told me, they are moved on the left.

Comment: the easiest way to go about that would be to wrap each iframe in a containing div and then use either display:flex; + justify-content:center; + align-items:center; on said container div or use percentual padding/margin values. Are those frames always 120px + 240px?

Comment: Yes, Iframes are always 120x240px.
I will try solution that you proposed, thanks.